# Preservation of meets by a *-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\varphi :A\to B$ be a *-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras. If I is a closed ideal of A, then one can consider $Id(\varphi (I))$, the closed ideal of B generated by the image $\varphi (I).$  Is it true that the operation $I\mapsto Id(\varphi (I))$ preserves meets? In other words, if $I$ and $J$ are closed ideals, does the following equality hold?
$$Id(\varphi (I\cap J))=Id (\varphi (I))\cap Id (\varphi (J))$$
If not, under what conditions is it true?

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $$\tag1Id(\varphi (I\cap J))\subset Id (\varphi (I))\cap Id (\varphi (J))$$ always holds. The converse can fail. For instance, let $A=\mathbb C^2$, $B=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and 
$$
\varphi(a,b)=\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Put $I=\mathbb C\oplus 0$, and $J=0\oplus \mathbb C$. Then $I\cap J=\{0\}$. So $$Id(\varphi (I\cap J))=\{0\},$$ while, as $B$ is simple, 
$$
Id(\varphi (I))=Id(\varphi (J))=M_2(\mathbb C). 
$$
The condition is obviously true when $\varphi$ is an isomorphism; I cannot think of another condition, as it could depend both on $\varphi$ and $A,B$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was my intuition but I wasn't sure as I'm not a specialist in this area. However, I think that it's true when we consider unital commutative C*-algebras. By Gelfand duality we can equivalently work with a continuous map between compact Hausdorff spaces. Then the problem can be restated as follows: the inverse image of a union of two closed subsets is the union of their corresponding inverse images, which is certainly true. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.